# Is not possible create directories and files at /Volumes with permissions granted

Tags: command-line, permission, user-account, folders

In Linux Ubuntu for example within the `/mnt` directory I created two directories - for example: `alpha` and `beta` - it to be used to mount some remote directories later.
For the same machine exists two users - for example: `manuel` and `leonardo` - where both have in common a new *secondary group* created and assigned to them named `developer` - it through the `gpasswd` command

To these directories were applied:

```
sudo chown -R root      <directory> # redundant
sudo chgrp -R developer <directory> 
sudo chmod -R 770       <directory>
```

If in the `/mnt` directory is executed `ls -ls` appears something like:

```
/mnt 
 drwxrwx--- root developer alpha
 drwxrwx--- root developer beta
```

Therefore because both users have the same `developer` *secondary group* and it is applied how the *primary group* for the two directories and the `g` has `rwx` they are able to use them in peace to accomplish any task as create either a directory or file.

With practically applying the same commands mentioned for Linux to MacOS - El Capitan - but with two differences:

- The users and group settings (creation and *secondary group* assignation) were done through `System Preferences`. About the *secondary group* assignation the `gpasswd` command does **not** exist on MacOS
- is used the `/Volumes` directory (it because`/mnt` does not exist on MacOS)

Through the `ls -ls` command appears:

```
/Volumes 
 drwxrwx--- root developer alpha
 drwxrwx--- root developer beta
```

The **problem** is when I try to execute either `mkdir zulu` or `touch delta.txt` through any user always appears:

```
mkdir: zulu: Permission denied
touch: delta.txt: Permission denied
```

If I execute for each one `id manuel` `id leonardo` I can see both have the `developer` *secondary group* assigned (same as Ubuntu)

**Note/Observation:** I know that the purpose to either `/mnt` and `/volumes` is to *mount* a directory. I am creating and deleting either a directory or file, mostly for the former just to test the users permissions for the following goal to accomplish.

**Goal**: I need that permission access because though Bash Shell within the `/mnt` (now for `/Volumes`) is created a nested directories structure - custom hierarchy - to **then** apply the *mount* process later. So in Ubuntu is possible but in mac not

### Commands

```
sudo -i # being root
cd /Volumes
mkdir omicron
chmod -R 770 omicron
chgrp -R developer omicron
```

with:

```
id manuel
...,504(developer),..
id leonardo
...,504(developer),..
```

Comment: Does this basically ask why a user belonging to group `developer` can not create a file within a directory owned by the same group?

Comment: I can't reproduce this here (can easily create files with `alpha`), but then I'm running Monterey (not El Capitan). You did `cd alpha` before touching `delta.txt`,  right?

Comment: Having said that: Your question would be a lot easier to understand if you omit the Ubuntu references (which won't help here) and just focus on what you are trying to do. It usually is also better to just post the relevant Terminal transcript (including any `cd`), and to run `id -a manuel` there as well.

Comment: @nohillside `Does this basically ask why a user belonging to group developer can not create a file within a directory owned by the same group?` Yes - `You did cd alpha before touching delta.txt, right?` Yes - I did do mention to Linux to indicate that the commands work as expected, furthermore  both are based on Unix/Linux and theoretically all the commands must work - but as I reported one command does not exist and in MacOS the expected behavior does not work.

Comment: About `id -a manuel` shows many groups, among them `developer` as expected.

Comment: Just like a plus if I do `cat /etc/group | grep developer` it shows **only** `_developer:*:204` but if I do `id a manuel` it shows `...,504(developer),...,204(_developer)` - why that difference? In Linux the output shows both groups for each command

Comment: macOS is not Linux, looking for similarities or differences when analyzing issues won't get you very far. Focus on the problem you want to solve, which steps you take and where they fail.

Comment: Well, I tried the things you probably did (can't fully verify because we don't see all the commands) and it worked (I can create files in a directory where my secondary group has write access). So either you made a typo somewhere, or things changed between El Cap and Monterey, or I did something different than you did.

Comment: I added the "Commands" section. Let me know what more info you need.

Comment: Can you run `ls -nd omicron` and check wether the group id on the directory is 504?

Comment: Yes - it shows `drwxrwx---+ 2 0 504 68 Feb 23 12:11 omicron`

Comment: @ManuelJordan The "+" in that `ls -l` output indicates the directory has an access control list in addition to basic POSIX permissions; use `ls -leO@` to display more info about the file (`-e` shows the ACL, `-O` adds any file flags, and `-@` shows extended attributes). BTW, /etc/group and /etc/passwd is not where actual users & groups are stored in macOS -- read the files, they both have comments at the beginning explaining this. Also, `gpasswd` is a Linux thing, not standard Unix; on macOS, look at `sysadminctl`, `dseditgroup`, and `dscl`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson huge thanks for pointing that - I am going to do a research about ACL and how it is reflected through `ls -l` to understand what is going on. Thanks for the other commands - more to research.